How to make MAKEFLAGS=--warn-undefined-variables apply to current Makefile?
Yes I read
Communicating Options to a Sub-'make'
but I want to set an option for this make, not a sub-make,
and set it within the Makefile, not via the command line.
$ cat Makefile
MAKEFLAGS = --warn-undefined-variables
zz: $(yy); xx
$ make -n # see, it didn't work!:
xx
$ make -n --warn-undefined-variables #need to do instead.
Makefile:2: warning: undefined variable 'yy'
xx
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3

Others had the same problem too.

From the GNU Make NEWS file, regarding changes made to the project for release 4.4.1:
Version 4.4.1 (26 Feb 2023)

This release is primarily a bug-fix release.
A complete list of bugs fixed in this version is available here:

https://sv.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?group=make&report_id=111&fix_release_id=110&set=custom

* WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
  In previous releases it was not well-defined when updates to MAKEFLAGS made
  inside a makefile would be visible.  This release ensures they are visible
  immediately, even when invoking $(shell ...) functions.  Also, command line
  variable assignments are now always present in MAKEFLAGS, even when parsing
  makefiles.
  Implementation provided by Dmitry Goncharov <dgoncharov@users.sf.net>

Also, for the 4.4 release (possibly related):
Version 4.4 (31 Oct 2022)

A complete list of bugs fixed in this version is available here:

https://sv.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?group=make&report_id=111&fix_release_id=109&set=custom

[...]

* If the MAKEFLAGS variable is modified in a makefile, it will be re-parsed
  immediately rather than after all makefiles have been read.  Note that
  although all options are parsed immediately, some special effects won't
  appear until after all makefiles are read.

Since you are using GNU Make 4.3, changes to the MAKEFLAGS variable are not immediately visible in the Makefile.

So good to know!  (Any temporary workarounds while we wait for Debian Sid to catch up?)

I don’t know of a workaround, but I’ll probably upload 4.4.1 at the end of October (see #1083140).
